# Strange things happening to my table view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton, uilabel

I have a table view. I originally used the cell's textLabel to handle this, but that didnt work, so i added a UILabel to each cell programatically and i have two buttons a add button and a subtract button which basically counts up or down when pressed. (goes up or down by 1) The methods for the two buttons are:

```
 - (IBAction)addLabelText:(id)sender{    
   cellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[cellLabel.text intValue] +1];

}  

- (IBAction)subtractLabelText:(id)sender
{
    if ( [[cellLabel text] intValue] == 0){ 
        cellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[cellLabel.text intValue] +0];
    }
    else{
        cellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[cellLabel.text intValue] -1];
    }
}
```

when i pressed the buttons, and added multiple cells, the buttons interfered with each other's labels. So i added this line of code to each of the above methods. :

```
    cellLabel = (UILabel*)[sender superview];
```

in hopes that it would fix the problem. But it actually added i believe the cells textLabel again. Here is a photo of what it looks like before and after i press one of the buttons with the new line added.

[image]

After:

[image]

any help with fixing the buttons interfering with each other cells UILabel's please help!! :D Thanks

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
     {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         newBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         newBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [newBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(280,10,25,55)];
         [newBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(subtractLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [newBtn setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [newBtn setEnabled:YES];
         [cell addSubview:newBtn];

         subBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         subBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [subBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(250,10,25,55)];
         [subBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [subBtn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [subBtn setEnabled:YES];
         [cell addSubview:subBtn];

         cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
         [cellLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(85, 22, 27, 27)];
         [cellLabel setText:@"1"];
         [cell addSubview:cellLabel];**
    } 
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
   // cell.textLabel.text = [cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    **if ([cell.imageView.image  isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle5.png"]]) {
        [cellLabel setFrame:CGRectMake (195, 22, 30, 30)];
    }
    if ([cell.imageView.image  isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle4.png"]]) {
        [cellLabel setFrame:CGRectMake (170, 22, 30, 30)];
    }
    if ([cell.imageView.image  isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle3.png"]]) {
        [cellLabel setFrame:CGRectMake (140, 22, 30, 30)];
    }
    if ([cell.imageView.image  isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle2.png"]]) {
        [cellLabel setFrame:CGRectMake (110, 22, 30, 30)];
    }**
return cell;
}
```

Comment: If you're building for iOS5, you might want to look into using a UIStepper instead of the two UIButtons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set tag to cell whet you cnfigurating it:
in my table I have some sections and some cells in every section. So, cells from first (0) section has tag 0...9999. from second - 10000...19999 adn so on. I mean tag of cell = 10000*number of section PLUS number of raw of this cell in ths section. then, to calculate what exacly is ths cell, I see how many 10000 tag has, to calculate from what sectiont it is, and how many >10000 tag has to calculate from what raw it is. So, I have section and raw from my table view.

```
cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.row+10000*indexPath.section; //or any you like
[cell.contentView addSubview:button]; //adding your button
```

then, in button's callback:

```
int row=0;
int section=0;
long tag = [sender superview].tag;
NSLog(@"tag: %ld", tag);
for (int i = 0; i<[data count]; i++) {
    if (tag>=10000) 
    {
        tag-=10000;
        section++;
    }
    else i = [data count];
}
row = tag;

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:section];
indexPath = [indexPath indexPathByAddingIndex:row];
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

now, you have full access to your cell. use calculated `raw` and `section` ta get access to cell.

Comment: I adited my answer. try this.

Comment: okay, shall i put this in the subtractLabelText method? Also, i copied and pasted your code and i am getting an error complaining about one of the ] brackets and i cannot figure it out! :/

Comment: yes, this code is for your `subtractLabelText` and `addLabelText` and sorry, i fixed it. Replace "-1"

Comment: ok thank you very much for the help! i switched out your `UILabel*label` line to my already created UILabel `cellLabel` however, when i press the button, the app crashes. And i read the console and it said: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'` Thanks again!:D

Comment: are you shure that you placed MINUS ONE? you have 5 objects [0 .. 4] and askiing for number 6, but it should be 4, the last one you added when configurated your cell (it was your label, right?).

Comment: yes when i have -1 the button does nothing now. But when i try to put +1 it crashes. and yes i changed the line to: `     cellLabel= [[cellNew subviews] objectAtIndex:[[cellNew subviews] count]-1];
` cellNew is what i renamed the UITableViewCell.

Comment: whell... in some reason easy way is not warking. Then, a little more code.

Comment: thanks for the help! and i post the first two lines in `cellForRow` and then all the other lines in the `addLabelText` method?

Comment: No, replace old code with new one. Yes, first two in `cellForRow` and all others in your button's callback. note, that adding your uston views (labels, buttons) to cell's contentView is good idea. It is more safety. Add all your view to cell's contentView, not to sell itself.

Comment: `data` - is my `NSMutableArray`. you should calculate this according your data storage

Comment: okay, i replaced the code for the cellForRow and it works perfect!;) but in my button's method, it says "data undeclared" and its an error. What is wrong with this? And just to make sure, this will add 1 to the value right? tHank you ! :D

Comment: okay i got the code working! :D may i ask what exactly all of this code does? Im having a hard time trying to figure it out! Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: in my table I have some sections and some cells in every section. So, cells from first (0) section has tag 0...9999. from second - 10000...19999 adn so on. I mean tag of cell = 10000*number of section PLUS number of raw of this cell in ths section. then, to calculate what exacly is ths cell, I see how many 10000 tag has, to calculate from what sectiont it is, and how many >10000 tag has to calculate from what raw it is. So, I have section and raw from my table view.

Comment: okay i think i understand. In your answer you said: "now, you have full access to your cell. use calculated raw and section ta get access to cell." how do i access the cell now? do i just do like i did before by adding +1 to my UILabel? Thank yoU!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5488/discussion-between-iprorage-and-sentinel)

Answer (score 1):

`[sender superview]` returns superview of your UIButton, which is UITableViewCell that also have `text` property so that's why your code still running fine even you casted it incorrectly.

Show us how you construct and add cellLabel so we can see what's wrong with it.